# image doesn't load when using template inheritance

Tags: html, google-app-engine, jinja2, template-engine

The image in the parent template doesn't load in the child one, instead it shows the 'alt'.
Here's how the structure goes.

"base.html"

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "x">
            <image src="x.jpg" alt="x">
        </div>
        <div class = "y">
            <a src="...">y</a>
        </div>
        <div id = "content">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

"child.html"

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
        ---replaced content
    {% endblock %}
```

content, y show in child normally, but x (the image) shows the alt text and can't load the image. This only happens when the image's src isn't a url, if it's it shows fine.

I'm using jinja2 template engine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I added the image to the directory containing all the static files other than just any directory and adding this directory path to the src. 
This happened because I configured the app.yaml handler like this

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

so whenever a url starts with '/static' it gets it from this directory and treats it as static file otherwise not.

This is very similar to this question 
[Jinja not rendering css/images in sub-directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434187/jinja-not-rendering-css-images-in-sub-directories)
and has nothing to do with jinja2 or its inheritance.

Comment: Bottom line, use absolute URLs when accessing images (and other resources).

Comment: Do you mean in the configuration file?
if yes, what's absolute vs relative URL in it (not in general) ?

Comment: I meant in the HTML. `src="x.jpg"` and `src="/x.jpg"` mean different things depending on the request. In most cases, you want to use the latter.